# How can I use a timecode when watching a youtube video with livestreamer?

Tags: youtube

I'd like to watch a youtube video via livestreamer, let's say by starting at 10 minutes into the video.

How can I do that? Is that even possible? The following code bits do not work:

- `livestreamer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk?t=10m`
- `livestreamer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk&?t=10m`
- `livestreamer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk&#t=10m`
- `livestreamer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk&t=10m`
- `livestreamer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk#t=10m`

**Note** Just in case one is interested in the program: [click here for another q&a on it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413993/how-can-i-improve-the-cpu-performance-when-i-watch-something-on-twitch-in-firefo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `vlc` (which `livestreamer` is based on):

```
vlc --start-time $((10*60)) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk"
```

Where `--start-time` is given the time offset in seconds.

For `livestreamer` I don't see any available [option](http://livestreamer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli.html#cli-options) right now to add this functionality. They downgraded the functionality of the wrapped `vlc` so to say :).

[Source](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aAdvanced_Use_of_VLC/#Video_options)

Comment: Finally got around to it and thank you. If anyone else is wondering: `$((10*60))` needs to be put without `s` for seconds or any other unit. So you'd have to write `1800` to start at 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the --player-continuous-http option and you can control the video within VLC. You may not be able to start at 10 min (haven't figured that out yet), but you will be able to seek within the video which is similar functionality and a bit more robust :)

```
livestreamer --player-continuous-http http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk
```